# Send string variable via TCP connection Lua

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I am sending data between two ESP8266 modules via TCP connection every 10 seconds in Lua:

```
string="abc"
cl=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
cl:connect(80,"192.168.4.1")
tmr.alarm(2, 10000, 1, function()
cl.send("The string variable is: "..string.."")end)
```

However, if I want to send string variable as in the code above, I keep getting error message:

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (init.lua:26: bad argument #1 to 'send' (net.socket expected, got string))
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (bad argument #1 (Server/Socket expected))
```

It works for me just when sending numerical variables. Is there any way to send string variable?

Thanks,
Kaki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is that the first argument to `send` call is expected to be the socket, not a string.

You should be using `cl:send("value")` instead of `cl.send("value")` as the first one is really a short form for `cl.send(cl, "value")`.

Comment: Thank you very much for a clear answer, it helped me a lot. Now it works :)